# Facebook Analytics - Get the share count for a Facebook post?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook analytics(https://developers.facebook.com/) to get the share number of counts for a facebook post (on a wordpress website), and it was working well until someone made some requests to the post(when i access the post in my website, i make a request to facebook api to get number of shares per post). After i make some requests to the post, example: http://kosovotwopointzero.com/sistemi-i-shendetesise-nen-mikroskop/ which currenty i disabled to show the number of shares because it doesn't work, the  facebook api is called:

This is the functions i use

```
function get_url_shares_count($url = '') {
    $fbUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com//v2.1/?id='.$url.'&access_token=??|??';
    $request = wp_remote_get($fbUrl);
    $data = json_decode($request['body']);

//  return $data[0]->share_count;
    return is_null($data->share) ? 0 : $data->share->share_count;
}
```

But almost of the time API is returning me this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "is_transient": true,
        "code": 4,
        "fbtrace_id": "GDs+M7u/zoO"
    }
}
```

Please can you help me to find a solution?Is this limitation something that facebook has as a policy or is the function that we are using?

If you help us find a solution either by any plugin that is working or a way on how to contact facebook (if this is necessary).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting // You should cache the results somewhere, instead of making a new API request upon every single page visit.

Comment: Are you using a user token, or an app-level token?

Comment: "??|??" suggests that he is using an app token. not a good idea to do that on every page hit.

Comment: Yes it's right. "??|??" is for token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest is to get the data either;

- once a hour
- everytime a user login again

how?

Something like this should work:

```
function YourFunctionName()
{
    $HourAgo = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time() -(3600));
    $newload = false;

    if (isset($_SESSION['LastApiCall'])) {
        if (strtotime($HourAgo) >= strtotime($_SESSION['LastApiCall'])) {
            $newload = true;
        }
    }else{
        $newload = true;
    }

    if ($newload) {
        $content = 'your_url'
        $_SESSION['apiData'] = json_decode($content);
       // Handle api data
        $_SESSION['LastApiCall'] = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    }
}
```

check YourFunctionName() everytime on reload, if a user is logging out destroy every session

*Note: didn't tested this*

Comment: Thank you Mike, i tried this but again it shows me the same "Application request limit reached". Can you please tell me if is it possible to somehow contact facebook for this problem.

Comment: Only one request if cache is expired otherwise none. But my site is very much frequented and have multiple requests. For example: i have cache for one post but when user try to access another post on my webpage there is another request and so on. And so far I've tested it if you do more than 120 requests within hours it will block you. I hope i was clear.

Comment: I see, Can you not cache all the post on loadup once a hour. Instead of reloading the post on every page .

Comment: I can but it is not something that suits me

Comment: Well, you are almost forced to do it. since otherwise you will have this problem the whole time, since facebook won't allow more request: 
developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting